# Integral of rational function using complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the integral:
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{x^4+x^2+1}dx.
$$
I can not see which path should I consider to compute the integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By symmetry, $$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{x^4+x^2+1}dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^2}{x^4+x^2+1}dx$$
Now, take a closed curve $\Gamma$ consisting of a line segment $(-\rho,\rho)$ and a semicircle from $-\rho$ to $\rho$ in $\mathcal{I}z\geq0$. Make $\rho$ large enough so $\Gamma$ encloses all poles in $\mathcal{I}z\geq0$. You can show that as $\rho \to \infty$ the integral along the semicircle goes to $0$. By the residue theorem, setting $f(z) = \frac{z^2}{z^4+z^2+1}$, $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^2}{x^4+x^2+1}dx = 2\pi i \sum_{\mathcal{I}z\geq 0} \textrm{Res }f(z)$$

$\textbf{Remark:}$ This is the general procedure for integrating a rational function across $\mathbb{R}$ when the degree of the denominator exceeds that of the numerator by at least $2$.